# Copying encrypted files to a non-encrypted folder using robocopy

Tags: windows, robocopy

If I use `robocopy` to copy encrypted files to a shared folder that does not support encryption, it fails with a

```
The specified file could not be encrypted.
```

This happens with or without the `/EFSRAW` flag.

Is there an equivalent for `robocopy` of the `/G` flag of `xcopy` that allows copying encrypted files to an unencrypted folder?

Comment: @harrymc *Not* a duplicate, I am asking specifically about `robocopy`, which is not mentioned in the other Q&A

Comment: But there is no solution with robocopy. You need to locally copy the files with EFS, unencrypt them, and then move to the shared folder.

Comment: Maybe you can explore using a file system for the share that is compatible with EFS  if the reader of the data once transferred is also expected to be able to decrypt it using EFS. If there is a require for encryption in transit and decrypting before transmitting is not an option, perhaps you need another file-level technology that is compatible across the source and destination file system such as PGP, Zip 256 bit AES, etc.? Depending on your requirements if any are applicable will depend on an ultimate solution your the end goal of your task.

Comment: @harrymc Ok thanks. It feels a bit awkward that `robocopy` is less capable than `xcopy` (or even plain `copy`) in that regard.

Comment: Robocopy uses the wrong Windows API for doing what you are asking for. Possibly some third-party product may do it better, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

You only get an error if the source folder is also encrypted and the destination folder is a root directory.`/nodcopy` flag seems to work in this case, although the file is created with system hidden attributes.